# Problem with jaxb2-maven-plugin and multiple xsd schemas generation

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xalan, schemagen

I have created a micro Maven project that reproduce exactly my problem.

[SchemaGen Maven Project on GitHub](https://github.com/zoffoliluca/SchemaGen)

I have multiple java classes (with Xml annotations) and I want to generate corresponding xsd schemas via jaxb2-maven-plugin.

When I do "mvn clean compile" I got this error :

```
[ERROR] : class org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to class org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler (org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @314b7945; org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @68c87fc3)
```

If I remove this Xalan dependency, all works perfectly.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xalan</groupId>
  <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Important :** I need to keep this Xalan dependency on my real project!

**Important 2:** If I comment one of the two executions on pom.xml, xsd generation works good

**Important 3:** I'm using Java OpenJdk 15

How can I keep Xalan dependency and get multiple xsd schemas generation works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by adding "scope runtime" in Xalan dependency :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xalan</groupId>
  <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.2</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now xsd schemas generation works properly.